# Coherence for closed bicategories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, 2-categories, kan-extension, coherence

A *right-closed bicategory* [1] is a bicategory that has all right extensions (i.e. right adjoints to precomposition with a fixed 1-cell). A one-object right-closed bicategory is therefore a right-closed monoidal category. (There are dual notions involving left extensions, and left and right lifts, corresponding similarly to left-closed and left- and right-coclosed monoidal categories.)

Is there a coherence theorem in the literature for right-closed bicategories, or can it be deduced from an existing result? I expect something like the following to be true:

*Every right-closed bicategory is biequivalent to a (strictly) right-closed 2-category.*

Here "strictly right-closed" would mean something like "composition of right extensions is strictly associative and unital".

[1]: Definition 16.3.1, May–Sigurdsson's [Parametrized Homotopy Theory](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/EXTHEORY/MaySig.pdf)

Comment: FWIW, note that the notion of closed bicategory (or closed monoidal category) is *not* one for which "all diagrams commute".  A counterexample for right-closed monoidal categories can be found in section 5 of Lambek's paper *Deductive systems and categories I*.  However, this example involves noninvertible maps, so it's not necessarily an obstacle to strictifying the associativity/unit isomorphisms for the right extensions as you suggest.